# alternating series test of $\sum(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to know if the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}$$ converges or not.
So I've tried the alternating series text:

1. $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}=0$ is clear.
2. I also need $a_{n+1}\leq a_n$.

So my question is if there is an very easy way to show 2. ? (I've tried to calculate the inequation but I don't get a nice result.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint:**

> $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}=\frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}$$

Clearly, $a_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: Which also shows that this sum absolutely converges.

Comment: so I have $\frac{1}{(n+1)(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1})}\leq\frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}$ but why does it help me?

Comment: This shows that $a_n$ is decreasing

Comment: sry but I don't see it :(

Comment: You wanted to show that $a_n\geq a_{n+1}$. Now you are done, because $a_n=\frac{1}{n(n^{0.5}+(n+1)^{0.5})}$ is decreasing

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @Amr is very nice and solves your problem. 
Here are some other approaches.

I. Let $a_n =  (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})/n$.
Then 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} 
&=& \frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}}{n+1} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}} \\
&=& \frac{n}{n+1}(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}) \\
&<& \frac{n}{n+1}(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}) \\
&=& \frac{n}{n+1}. 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

II. Since 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \sim 1 - \frac{3}{2n} + \ldots
\qquad (n\to\infty)$$
the series converges absolutely by [Raabe's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to define a function $f$ where $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}{x}$ you get

$f'(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{{x}^{2}+x}-x-2}{2{x}^{2}{\cdot}\sqrt{x+1}}$ which is strictly negative since $\sqrt{x^2+x}<x+2$ hence $f$ is decreasing and so is $a_n$.